# How does atan(1) * 4 equal PI?

Tags: pi

I needed the PI constant in C++, and I was lead to the answer that:

```
const PI = atan(1) * 4
```

Note that despite involving code, I'm asking this from a mathematics perspective.

I have 2 questions about this:

- Is this an estimation of PI, or should it give me a large degree of accuracy?
- How does this give PI?

On the second point, if I understand `atan` correctly, it takes a ratio of two sides, and returns the corresponding angle.

That means that `atan(1)` is referring a situation with 2 equal length sides.

I think I'm misunderstanding something though, as `atan(1)` gives me `0.7853981633974483`, which seems like a very tiny angle.

If anyone can fill in the holes, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I use `pi = acos(-1)` in C++, as I consider it neater.

Comment: ... and I use `const pi=3.1415926535897932384626433`, but that's mostly because I cannot remember to simply use the predefine `M_PI` (cf. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727881/how-to-use-the-pi-constant-in-c))

Comment: But in both these cases you must make sure you are in radian mode, not degree.  The arctan of 1 is 45 degrees.

Comment: As @GEdgar hints, the value of atan(1) you're looking at there is in [radians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian). This is the standard measure of angle in mathematics. You can think of this as measuring angle by measuring the length of circumference of a unit circle included by that angle. $2\pi$ radians is the whole circle, ie. 360 degrees.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen How can you live with truncating before an $8$ rather than a smaller digit? :)

Comment: Is there any advantage of `atan(1) * 4` over `acos(-1)`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The function $\arctan\colon \mathbb{R}\to (-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$ is the inverse of $\tan$. (for the right domain of definition). As $\tan \frac{\pi}{4} = 1$, this means that $\arctan 1=\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Regarding your question about angles: angles are (in mathematics) measured in radians (in $[0,2\pi)$ or $[-\pi,\pi)$), not in degrees: you should expect a value or order $\pi$ or so, *not* ranging between $0$ and $360$.

Comment: You can see this readily if you consider that $\theta = \dfrac \pi 4$ satisfies $\sin \theta = \cos \theta$

Comment: the terms used for the inverse function of $tan,$ i know of,  are either $\tan^{-1}$ or $arctan.$ the reciprocal is reserved for $\frac{1}{\tan}$

Comment: @abel : my bad, translation issues. Will edit my post.

Comment: clement, no problem.  native english speaking students stumble over this all the time.

Answer (score 16):

I'm including this little gif from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) as a great way to understand radians.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You certainly know that $\sin{\frac{\pi}{4}}=\cos{\frac{\pi}{4}}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ so one has $\tan{\frac{\pi}{4}}=1$ and therefore $\pi=4\tan^{-1}{1}$

Answer (score 1):

Math explanation from a non-math person:

In a right angled triangle if the two short sides are equal, the angle is 45 degrees.

45 degrees in radians is π/4. (The full circumference is 2πr, 180 degrees is π and 45 degrees is π/4)

sin π/4 = cos π/4 because the two sides are equal.

tan π/4 = tan 45 = 1.

Arctan(1) is the degree (or radian) which returns a value of 1. So arctan of 1 is either 45 degrees or π/4.

π = 4*arctan(1)

Answer (score 1):

This shows geometric explanation for relationship between tan, atan and Pi.

Because horizontal segment AB = 1 and vertical segment BD = 1, angle alpha = 45°. From there you can use atan( BD ) to determine 45° in radiant and take that times 4 to get Pi.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, in all numeric programing languages like fortran, c, c++,  and many others, for a program generalized input line that looks something like:

```
    print, numeric,  %pi , acos(-1), 4*atan(1)
```

all return the same numeric value. Here the system stored value %pi may be faster than trig evaluation.

```
    3.141592653589793, 3.141592653589793, 3.141592653589793
```